# Saving images in sqlite from a webservice generated URL

Tags: android, image, web-services, android-intent, imageview

In my project call to the `webservice` generates URL of images which is different each time and it is timed which wont work like any other URL. When i click on that URL images gets downloaded in my drives. But i want to save it in my db.

I Have seen [this Link](http://www.getablogger.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html) and tried with it. But for my auto generated URL type that code wont work. Anyone has idea about how to get to know how to save the **webservice auto generated URL** in my sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i analyzed the problem what i think is you will have two ways doing it

1) Storing the downloaded image inside sqlite and displaying it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304703/download-an-image-and-store-in-sqlite-in-android-local-db/11305051#11305051

2)or else just do how they have done in this blog
 http://www.getablogger.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html

may be you might get better way. 
ALL THE BEST